# How to change a toggle to false when another toggle is true

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm getting stackoverflows when I try my logic of switching one toggle off and switching another one on.

I have 2 toggles. They both listen to 2 different properties in the VM (`IsAddAppleEnabled` and `IsAddOrangeEnabled`).

I want it so that when `IsAddAppledEnabled` is true, `IsAddOrangeEnabled` is false... and vice versa.

I tried doing it in there setters but I end up getting in a loop and get a stackoverflow exception

```
    private bool isAddAppledEnabled= false;
    public bool isAddAppledEnabled
    {
        get { return isAddReplicateToggleChecked; }
        set
        {
            isAddAppledEnabled= value;
            isAddOrangeEnabled= !value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddAppledEnabled));
        }
    }

    private bool isAddOrangeEnabled= false;
    public bool IsAddOrangeEnabled
    {
        get { return isAddOrangeEnabled; }
        set
        {
            isAddOrangeEnabled= value;
            isAddAppledEnabled= !value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddOrangeEnabled));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Setting the "isAddAppledEnabled" set "isAddAppledEnabled = value;" - which causes infinite recursion - hence the stackoverflow. Did you intend the property to be named "IsAddAppledEnabled" similar to "IsAddOrangeEnabled" with a private backing field.

Comment: yes sorry made a small change, bad copy and paste

Comment: Note that you may only need 1 private Boolean field if one property will be always true & the false. The get property for on returns the value of the private Boolean field the other returns the value not'ed. Similar for setting.

Comment: PaulF could you give an example?

Comment: Just use two radiobuttons. Template them as togglebuttons if you must.

Comment: They seem to always be the opposite of the other. Why two properties?

Comment: tbh they aren't always the opposite of one another...from what I have, if one is true, the other should be set to false, but if that one that is true is set to false, the other remains false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the backing fields and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for both properties. You are also returning the wrong value from the `IsAddAppledEnabled` property. Try this:

```
private bool _isAddAppledEnabled;
public bool IsAddAppledEnabled
{
    get { return _isAddAppledEnabled; }
    set
    {
        _isAddAppledEnabled= value;
        _isAddOrangeEnabled= !value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddAppledEnabled));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddOrangeEnabled));
    }
}

private bool _isAddOrangeEnabled;
public bool IsAddOrangeEnabled
{
    get { return _isAddOrangeEnabled; }
    set
    {
        _isAddOrangeEnabled= value;
        _isAddAppledEnabled= !value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddOrangeEnabled));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddAppledEnabled));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note my comment above - if the two properties will always be the opposite to each other - then isAddOrangeEnabled is not required. The getter for IsAddOrangeEnabled can return ! isAddAppledEnabled.

Comment: @PaulF: Yes,  but then you cannot set `IsAddOrangeEnabled` individually.

Comment: Yes you can - it is already setting _isAddAppledEnabled to !value - just remove the line setting _isAddOrangeEnabled in the setter.

Comment: @PaulF: To clarify, you cannot set `IsAddOrangeEnabled` without setting the other property. I guess the OP has one control bound to `IsAddOrangeEnabled`.

Comment: _"public bool IsAddOrangeEnabled { get { return ! IsAddAppledEnabled; }      set { IsAddAppledEnabled= !value; } }"_ removes the need for _isAddOrangeEnabled

Comment: One toggle button has `IsAddOrangeEnabled` bound to the `IsChecked` of the toggle, and the other toggle button has `IsAddAppleEnabled` bound to the `IsChecked` of that toggle

Comment: yes.. it works... not sure why though... how comes this breaks the infinite loop?

Comment: @uaswpf: Because you don't set the other property. You set the backing field and then tell the framework to query the getter of this property by raising the event.

Comment: Ah... I see.... then could you not just call the property instead of setting the backing field and doing an `OnPropertyChanged`? i.e. assign the property rather than the backing field?

Comment: If you set property B which in turn sets property A which sets property B again and so on, you will eventually run out of stack space and get a `StackOverflowException`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option A (minimal approach change)**:

```
private bool _isAddAppledEnabled = false;
public bool IsAddAppledEnabled
{
  get { return _isAddAppledEnabled; }
  set
  {
    if (_isAddAppledEnabled == value)
      return;

    _isAddAppledEnabled = value;
    IsAddOrangeEnabled = !value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddAppledEnabled));
  }
}

private bool _isAddOrangeEnabled = false;
public bool IsAddOrangeEnabled
{
  get { return _isAddOrangeEnabled; }
  set
  {
    if (_isAddOrangeEnabled == value)
      return;

    _isAddOrangeEnabled = value;
    IsAddAppledEnabled = !value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddOrangeEnabled));
  }
}
```

**Option B (bool inversion converter)**:
You could use a single property in the view model and utilize converters so the xaml can react differently based on the states.

One example would be to simply use a bool (like you are) and apply an *inversion converter*:

```
  public class InvertedBooleanConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {

      if (value == null || (bool)value == false)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value == null || (bool)value == false)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      return this;
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
  <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAddAppledEnabled}">
  <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsAddAppledEnabled, Converter={yourNamespace:InvertedBooleanConverter}}">
```

**Option C (enum converter)**:
Another option that may work better if you end up with a additional mutually-exclusive states would be to *use an enum*.

Converter

```
  public class EnumToBooleanConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      return this;
    }
  }
```

ViewModel:

```
public enum Fruits { Apple, Orange, Pear, Grape }

private Fruits _selectedFruit;
public Fruits SelectedFruit
{
  get { return _selectedFruit; }
  set
  {
    _selectedFruit = value;
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFruit));
  }
}
```

Xaml usage:

```
<RadioButton Content="Apple" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedFruit, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={yourNamespace:EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static yourNamespace:Fruits.Apple}}"/>
<RadioButton Content="Orange" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedFruit, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={yourNamespace:EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static yourNamespace:Fruits.Orange}}"/>
<RadioButton Content="Pear" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedFruit, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={yourNamespace:EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static yourNamespace:Fruits.Pear}}"/>
<RadioButton Content="Grape" IsChecked="{Binding Path=SelectedFruit, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={yourNamespace:EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static yourNamespace:Fruits.Grape}}"/>
```

Comment: Converters are the way to go in WPF

Answer (score 0):

You create endless recursion in property set `isAddAppledEnabled`,
name of property is `isAddAppledEnabled` and you call it in set recursivly.

```
 isAddAppledEnabled= value;
```

change to

```
IsAddAppledEnabled = value
```